# SharePoint 2010 Custom Site Definition - master page gallery new sub folders in pending status oddity

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've created a custom site definition for SP2010, in the definition is a custom master page with several custom page layouts that are nested in some new sub folders. The problem i'm having is after deployment of the solution the new folders that contain my custom page layouts have a pending status even though the individual master page and layouts files do have approved status, which is inconsistent.

My question is how can I ensure all items folders and files I've deployed to master page gallery have an approved status with deploy of a custom site definition solution in SP2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no solution to this problem other than to manually approve the folders or write a script or some code to do it.